# How to restore wheel group on macOS sierra 10.12.6

Tags: macos, hard-drive

I stupidly deleted wheel group under info in Macintosh HD. Then Everything on my desktop disappeared, I had no access to anything. It was a blank canvas. I turned it off manually, and then when I turned it back on and entered password it gets stuck in loading and nothing happens. Also nothing happens when I hit Command S on restart. When I hit Command R I was able to get into terminal and tried all the commands you guys answered in a very similar question, but nothing worked. I am not able to download Batchmod because I can't access internet.
Is there any other solution for this issue? I had a lot of unsaved things and programs I would hate to lose. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Boot to Recovery & re-install the OS.

Don't erase the drive first, just reinstall. It will restore the OS without erasing user data.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140006/discussion-on-answer-by-tetsujin-how-to-restore-wheel-group-on-macos-sierra-10-1).